# Subaggregation results are not properly showing

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Java Springdata elasticsearch and I want to use sub-aggregation and model the following query.

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 10,
  "sort" : [ {
    "_score" : {
      "order" : "desc"
    }
  } ],
  "aggregations" : {
    "parentAgg" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "parentField",
        "size" : 0
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "childAgg" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "childField"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Currently I have used subaggregation (i.e. Aggregation.subAggregation(subAggName)) however output I get is -

```
"aggregations": [
    {
      "field": "parentAgg",
      "values": [
        {
          "term": "val1",
          "docCount": 2
        },
        {
          "term": "val2",
          "docCount": 2
        },
        {
          "term": "val3",
          "docCount": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Relavent Java Code -

```
for (Object aggregationField : request.getAggregationFields()) {
            TermsBuilder termBuilder = AggregationBuilders.terms(aggregationField.toString())
                    .field(aggregationField.toString()).size(0);
            if(aggregationField.toString().equals("parentField"))
            {
                TermsBuilder childBuilder = AggregationBuilders.terms("childAgg").field("childField").size(0);
                termBuilder.subAggregation(childBuilder);
            }               
            nativeSearchQueryBuilder.addAggregation(termBuilder);
        }
```

Can you please let me know what I am missing?

Comment: Seems like u missed the proper field name -`if(aggregationField.toString().equals("parentField"))`

Comment: My bda, it was typo, actually I am doing right comparison i.e. as you mentioned if(aggregationField.toString().equals("parentField")) [edited the question.]. However when i debug the code then execution goes inside the if conditional and finally the query which is generated, when run from sense/postman then gives correct results however reponse from springData side includes only parent level aggregation, i.e. sub aggregation is not happening.